# How do you get the model.id from the collection.create call?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to use the model id from the COLLECTION.create call to redirect the user to do new page

```
window.href = 'https://example.com/document/' + model.id
```

I do not care if the ajax call to the rest api is async or sync (if that matters). I was hoping  I could do something like this:

```
var OPTS ={}
OPTS['success'] = function( response, model, options ){
                model.id
}

SOMECOLLECTION.create(json_attributes,OPTS)
```

But that does not work. I am using Django-Tastypie as my REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/echo/json/'
});

var my_collection = new MyCollection();

var model = my_collection.create({ name: "Eugene", age: 31 }, {

    success: function(response, model) {
        console.log(model.id);
        // id: 123
    }

});

console.log(model.id);
// id: undefined
```

I created working example here http://jsfiddle.net/6wup7q9e/3/

Please check your network tab to see what response you have from your REST API, it should have and your `json_response` and new `id` attribute which will be used as a model id. In my case it will be something like:

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Eugene",
    age: 31
}
```